# How does fs.createReadStream in node.js works internally

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't understand how does fs.createReadStream work in node.js.

I've sample code :

```
var fs = require('fs');


var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/read.text');

stream.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('new chunk arrived');
    console.log(chunk);
    console.log('');
})

stream.on('close', function(){
    console.log('file closed')
})

stream.on('end', function(){
    console.log('stream ended')
})

stream.on('open', function(){
    console.log('File opened')
});

console.log('one');
console.log('two');
```

In this code when will the chunk from the file will start streaming?

when we declare an object on line?

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/read.text');
```

on this line?

```
 stream.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('new chunk arrived');
    console.log(chunk);
    console.log('');
})
```

or when the entire code is executed?

synchronously or asynchronously?

I'll be grateful if you explain code line by line.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) which provides all the requested information?

Answer (score 2):

javascript is full asynchronous,

a function createReadStream call events in the following order,

- open : your file exist and it's open
- data : nodejs read content and call data event for every chunks (size default: 64kb)
- end : all data are in stream
- close : file closed

in the line

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/read.text');
```

you create a stream, is empty, but the process for getting data start, suscribing event never start process,